# Air fare refund & reschduled

Tags: airports

I booked a flight today at 10.30 pm but suddenly the flight time rescheduled to 8pm on that same day & i am unknown of that fact . Is it possible to get refunded?

Comment: Possibly. Where are you flying from and to and on which airline?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. The answer depends very much upon the terms and conditions of the ticket you purchased and where you are flying; at a minimum, we would need to know your origin and destination andthe airline you are flying, and when and how you were notified of the change.

Comment: Are you saying the airline didn't notify you of the change? Do you wish to travel on the rescheduled flight, or are you asking that you want to take the later flight (which is now no longer available) and are thus looking to reschedule or possibly have the ticket refunded?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the airline and you will have to contact them to find out exactly.

You should ask about their policies regarding two things:

1. Schedule change window.  The airline should have a policy that gives the maximum time they can reschedule the flight before offering re-accommodation or a refund.  American Airlines is 4 hours for example if I recall correctly.
2. Trip in vain.  This means that a schedule change or delay would make the trip meaningless such as missing a meeting or cruise ship for example because of the different departure time.  Basically, there's no point in flying.

Comment: Sorry, but the downvotes are totally unwarranted, especially with no explanation.  This is how the OP can address the problem.  There is other advice we can give other than how to address this with the airline.